# missing ')' before identifier '��'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am going through a book to learn C++ and copied this straight from it;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter true (1) or false (0) for two operands:" << endl;
    bool Op1 = false, Op2 = false;
    cin >> Op1;
    cin >> Op2;

    cout << Op1 << " AND " << Op2 << " = " << (Op1 && Op2) << endl;
    cout << Op1 << " OR " << Op2 << " = " << (Op1 ¦¦ Op2) << endl;


    Sleep(60000);

    return 0;
}
```

I added the windows.h and sleep function, but apart from that it's identical. It keeps saying - lesson5.cpp(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '¦¦'

I've been trying to fix it for about half an hour now but can't find any solutions on the internet. Anyone please help me? It seems very strange and I hope it's something glaringly obvious that I'm just missing.

Comment: Watch out copying code from this book.  It was typeset with non-standard ASCII characters.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, that `windows.h` include is just atrocious.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Why? It's the documented way to get the declaration of `Sleep`. (Of course, the use of `Sleep` does seem rather unnecessary.)

Comment: Sure, I meant that using `Sleep` here is not needed. :P

Comment: Calling system("pause") so you can see the console window output doesn't win prizes either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seens to be wrong chars here: `(Op1 ¦¦ Op2)`.
It should be: `(Op1 || Op2)`

Comment: Ah great, thank you, it is literally written ¦¦ in the book. Sorry for the rookie question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't copy and paste code from documents/PDF as they may contain characters which are not valid C++.

So just type this part `(Op1 ¦¦ Op2)` yourself as `(Op1 || Op2)`.

Comment: I did actually write it out, its from a physical book, I just would not have known the symbol was incorrect as it isn't suggested at all in the book. Thanks for the pointer though.